# Added jar in BootStrap location is not reflecting in My Classes using Eclipse

Tags: java, jvm

Please help me to understand whats wrong with this.
I added a jar in a BootStrap location of

> jdk(C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_27\lib\ext)  and in jre(C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jre1.6.0_22\lib\ext)

but jar class is not reflecting while try to invoke methods or classes added by jar in Eclipse.

**Also help me to know where I can see the printed things by static block by Logs.......**

Below I included the class I used to create the JAR.

```
package test.classloader;

public class BootStrapTest {
    static
    {
        System.out.println("BootStrap Jar is Loaded....................");
    }
    public static String checkClassLoader()
    {       
        return "This is BootStrap Class Check ClassLoader";     
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to take a stab at the reason behind why you think you need to do this.  Excuse me if I am incorrect but you provide vague information and it is unclear what your question is.

If you need missing Java EE libs  (or other 3rd party libs) in Eclipse, add one of the sofware REPOs (to your Eclipse software manager) listed on this URL and then install the Java EE libs from it: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/

Or, use Maven as a build tool and add the appropriate dependency to download the lib that your project needs.